# Was a question migrated to Web Applications by mistake?

Tags: discussion, migration, specific-question

When I reviewed this question: [feed XML to google calendar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/80361/feed-xml-to-google-calendar) on Superuser Q&A, my review was that it would be a better match for Stack Overflow Q&A because of the XML topic, but it got migrated to Web Applications anyway. One of the people who reviewed it has difficulty understanding English, and I'm not sure if this question was reviewed correctly. On the other hand, getting Google Calendar to work properly may justify accepting a small amount of XML coding in the topic.

Is this question sufficiently on topic that it should remain at Web Applications?

Comment: For what it's worth, [su] doesn't have a very good track record in migrating questions here. Things that obviously should be migrated very often are not, and others that should not are, sometimes with only the thinnest connection to a web app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering that

1. Google Calendar web UI doesn't have anything that could help,
2. If I would like to research in order to write an anwser to that Q, I would start by looking at Google Developers, actually I would go directly [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/)

So, IMHO, the related Q should be migrated to StackOverflow.

Comment: I tend to agree with Rubén. The question should have been migrated to [so]. However, since we don't "double-migrate", unless the Mods at [su] re-open it there and migrate again, all we can do is close it and encourage the Asker to ask again in a more appropriate venue.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that shouldn't have been migrated to Web Apps. I've closed it here, reopened and migrated that question to Stack Overflow. Thanks for bringing it to our notice